# Website resolves with old IP address - only on my computer

Tags: networking, dns, ip

So I've been in touch with my hosting as I'm locked out of my website due to it resolving with my old ip address (I have tested this - i'm locked out due to the fact my old ip address just displays an ssl certificate error whereas my new ip just displays my wordpress login). I have tried switching DNS severs and flushing my DNS cache. I have tried the same webpage on other computers in the same network and they don't have the same issue.

Comment: What is the result of `nslookup <YourWantedPage>`?

Comment: Can you find the wanted server in the [host file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)?

Comment: @boboes I had a look at my host file and for some reason it was pointing to my old IP address - I have no idea how/why! Anyways I changed it and the problem is all solved now!! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Open the [host file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and delete the entry for the server.